# How do I run a selenium test using maven from the command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

I currently use Eclipse as my Java IDE and I use Maven. I click the run button and it is able to run a Selenium Java test I wrote.

I then proceeded to install Maven on my local machine.

After going to the directory where my pom.xml file is located.
I run the command: mvn test

I receive the following results:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBu
ilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SeleniumWebDriver 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SeleniumWebDriver ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platfo
rm dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ SeleniumWebDriver ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ SeleniumWebDriver ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platfo
rm dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SeleniumWebDriver ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ SeleniumWebDriver ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.139 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-03-17T14:12:27-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/99M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I do not understand why the Firefox webbrowser does not start, and a test is ran. When running the same test in the Eclipse IDE the Firefox webBrowser does start.

It seems to compile fine, but it is for some reason not testing or kicking off the browser when it has the .class files after compilation.

here is a copy of my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SeleniumWebDriver</groupId>
  <artifactId>SeleniumWebDriver</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.40.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.40.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.40.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Running maven with -Dtest parameter does the trick;like: `mvn -Dtest=your.package.DemoTest test`. FMI, see https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-run-a-selenium-test-with-junit

Answer (score 11):

This is a older thread, but still want to provide input for those who are stuck up at this. You have to make sure that the class file names you are creating are ending with "Test" string.
e.g. AppTest, TempTest are all valid class file names, but AppCheck, TempTest1 are invalid name; maven will not detect these files for execution.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see this until after I had posted [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643006/how-can-i-run-my-selenium-tests-with-maven)...and subsequently found an answer to it!  I've included my answer below:

Maven can be made to run the code it compiles by using the exec-maven-plugin and adding the following to the pom.xml:

```
    <build>
     <plugins>
      <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.1</version>
       <executions>
        <execution>
         <phase>test</phase>
         <goals>
          <goal>java</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
          <mainClass>Selenium2Example</mainClass>
          <arguments>
           <argument>arg0</argument>
           <argument>arg1</argument>
          </arguments>
         </configuration>
        </execution>
       </executions>
      </plugin>
     </plugins>
    </build>
```

As you can probably gather from the snippet, arguments can be passed in by listing them in the pom.xml. Also, be sure to use the proper package name in the `mainClass` element.

You can then run `mvn compile` followed by `mvn test` to compile and run your code.

Credit has to go to http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/ for listing several ways to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [Maven Failsafe](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) (for integration tests), or Surefire (for unit tests).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to your directory structure.  Maven uses an [arbitrary directory structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

- `src/main/java` is your main java code
- `src/test/java` is your tests.  Maven will read THIS directory when executing `mvn test` by default.

You have two options:

1. Update your pom to something like:

   `<build> 
     <sourceDirectory>src/java</sourceDirectory> 
     <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory> 
     ...
   </build>`
2. Abide by Maven convention and put your test sources under `src/test/java`