# How can I run my Selenium tests with Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

I'm trying to figure out how to run Selenium WebDriver tests without having to use Eclipse or IntelliJ or any other IDE. I do all my java development using a plain text editor, and don't want to have to install (and learn) an IDE just for the sake of compiling and running tests.

I've tried following the Selenium documentation, but it stops short of actually telling you how to run the tests from the command line.

My brief experience with maven amounts to the following:

```
    $ mvn compile
    <snip>
    No sources to compile

    $ mvn test
    <snip>
    No tests to run

    $ mvn run
    <snip>
    Invalid task 'run'
```

The only other one I know is `mvn jetty:run` but that doesn't seem right as I'm not wanting to run a new web server.

I suspect I just need to set the correct targets etc in my pom.xml, but I don't know what they should be, and surprisingly can't find any online.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: https://easytolearnautomationtesting.wordpress.com/maven-integration-with-automation-script/ This will help you the better understanding about execute the script through maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally figured it out after realising that this is actually a Maven-specific question rather than Eclipse or Selenium.

Maven can be made to run the code it compiles by using the exec-maven-plugin and adding the following to the pom.xml:

```
    <build>
     <plugins>
      <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.1</version>
       <executions>
        <execution>
         <phase>test</phase>
         <goals>
          <goal>java</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
          <mainClass>Selenium2Example</mainClass>
          <arguments>
           <argument>arg0</argument>
           <argument>arg1</argument>
          </arguments>
         </configuration>
        </execution>
       </executions>
      </plugin>
     </plugins>
    </build>
```

As you can probably gather from the snippet, arguments can be passed in by listing them in the pom.xml. Also, be sure to use the proper package name in the `mainClass` element.

You can then run `mvn compile` followed by `mvn test` to compile and run your code.

Credit has to go to http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/ for listing several ways to do this.

Comment: Actually, what people usually do is use the Maven Surefire or Failsafe plugins.  That way you don't need to run it like you are above: which is similar to running it on the command line.  Surefire already binds itself to the 'test' phase by default.

Answer (score 1):

## In short:

`mvn integration-test` or `mvn verify` is the thing you're looking for.

## Explanation

The goals, you're invoking, are lifecycle phases of maven (see [Maven Lifecycle Reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)). `mvn test` is intended for standalone unit tests, `mvn integration-test` runs after compiling, testing and packaging. That would be also the phase, where you invoke Selenium tests. If you need to start and stop Jetty, Tomcat, JBoss, etc., you would bind start/stop of these to `pre-integration-test` and `post-integration-test`.

I usually run my integration-tests using [Failsafe](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) and perform there invocations to Selenium and other integrative tests.