# Test deployment of a servlet

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets

I am working on a servlet (containing a Jersey REST server) which I ship in the `war` format. I wrote extensive unit tests to thoroughly test the code base. However, I often have the problem that the war does not start correctly.

This is mostly due to me making some kind of mistake in the `web.xml` file. For example, I rename some class mentioned in the xml without changing the corresponding line in the xml itself. The problem is that in my tests I create a *debug* [Application](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs-javax.jax-rs/2.0.1/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) so the xml is never considered. More to the point, lets say I have the following (Jersey) `ResourceConfig`:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class MyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
  public MyConfig() {
    register(...);
  }
}
```

Now suppose I have an error in the `web.xml`:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
  <param-value>MyMisspelledConfig</param-value>
</init-param>
```

My unit tests look like this:

```
public class ServerTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new MyConfig();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
      //...
    }

}
```

The tests pass but the deployed servlet won't even start...

Is there a way to automatically test the *default* deployment (including the `web.xml`)?

Comment: Could you show us some code to give a better context around your question?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know for testing the *deployment descriptor* `web.xml` is to deploy the war on a local server on the developper machine (tomcat or jetty are good candidates). Netbeans or Eclipse offer nice integration for that, opening a browser window to the root of the web application.

You can then manually view some pages, or if you prefere automated tests, you can use the excellent [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) that plays some recorded scenarii controlling portions of the received pages.

Comment: Well, I could use some bash scripts to do create a war package, deploy it, start the server and perform some tests. But I was hoping this would be possible in a Junit-like fashion.

Comment: You could have to look to that other [post from SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22462181/) that shows that maven can automate the build and a Selenium test as integration test.